# Realizar un redireccionamiento con base al "confirm"

Tags: javascript

Lo que deseo realizar es un redireccionamiento a otra página una vez que el usuario confirme dicha acción.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var pagar = document.getElementById(claspagar); 
        claspagar.onclick = function(){(if confirm (location.href = ("checkout.html"))};
             else("Continua comprando")
             }
        }
```

Soy novato y estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta, me gustaría saber si está implementado de la manera correcta, en el Dreamweaver me marca un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, toma el [tour] y lee con atención [ask].

Comment: Lo siento acabo de ver sobre cómo preguntar. Debo eliminar mi pregunta ?

Comment: Hola fabricio benvenido a SO en Español, Que quieres lograr con eso? una redirección?

Comment: Hola, sí en caso que el confirm sea afirmativo debe enviar a una página web.

Comment: @Fabricio ¿el código te funciona?, ¿te da un error?. Edita tu publicación para añadir dicha información que pueda apoyar a enriquecer tu pregunta y pasar de ser una pregunta de carácter «subjetivo» a «objetivo». Así podrás tener una respuesta concreta a tu duda, con la mayor información posible. Creeme que habemos muchas personas con el objetivo de apoyarte, sólo apóyanos a hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias por tus sugerencias ahora lo hago, es la primera vez que utilizo SO. Lamento los errores en mi publicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ver el código línea a línea para ver qué está bien y qué está (o puede estar) mal:

```
window.onload = function(){
```

Esta lína no tiene fallo a simple vista.

```
    var pagar = document.getElementById(claspagar);
```

Esta línea puede contener un fallo. `claspagar` es una variable, si no está definida, recibirás un error aquí. Si está definido, entonces pagar tendrá el elemento con ID definido en la variable `claspagar`.

Las siguientes partes las voy a separar en diferentes líneas para analizarlas poco a poco:

```
    claspagar.onclick = function(){
```

Esto es un error, o bien lo era el paso anterior. So `claspagar` es una cadena con el ID de un elemento, entonces no se le podrá asignar un evento `onclick`, si es un elemento sí se le podrá asignar un controlador del click, pero entonces el paso anterior fallaría. Lo que me imagino es que en lugar de `claspage.onclick` lo que quieres hacer es `pagar.onclick`.

```
      (if confirm (location.href = ("checkout.html"))
```

La sintaxis de esto es incorrecta. La comprobación del `if` debería ir entre paréntesis, además, hay tres paréntesis de apertura y sólo dos de cierre.

```
    };
```

Este cierre correspondería a la función de `claspagar.onclick`, lo que hará que la siguiente parte sea incorrecta:

```
         else("Continua comprando")
         }
```

Este código está huérfano. Debería ir con el `if`, pero como se cerró incorrectamente, no tiene sentido. Además, ("Continua comprando") es sólo una cadena y no tiene sentido por sí sola, supongo que quieres que vaya con un `console.log` o un `alert`. La llave de cierre no corresponde a ninguna llave de apertura (falta una en el `else`).

```
    }
```

Este sería el cierre de la función window.onload y está bien.

---

Solucionando los errores de arriba, el código quedaría como esto (suponiendo que `claspagar` es una variable con el nombre del ID; si es el nombre en sí, deberías entrecomillarlo):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var pagar = document.getElementById(claspagar); 
    pagar.onclick = function(){
        if (confirm("Estás seguro?")) {
            location.href = "checkout.html";
        } else {
            alert("Continua comprando");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eres un crack gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que quieres lograr una dirección a otra pagina web el confirm esta mal implementado, lo que quieres hacer podrias hacerlo asi:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var r = confirm("Seguir comprando?");
  if (r == true) {
    alert("Confirm aceptado"); //alert para comprobar la opción elegida
    //aqui haces la redirección, podrias usa location.href

    /************REDIRECCION**********/
    //window.location.href = "http://ejemplo.com";
    
  } else {
    alert("Confirm cancelado");
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entiendo los errores que cometí. Me salvaste.